# How can I install Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 8 on Big Sur

Tags: macos, netbeans, netbeans-8, macos-big-sur

I am having a problem with installing Netbeans 8.2 on my new MacBook Pro 13 (M1). I already have Netbeans 8.2 installed on my PC desktop, but I can't install it on my Mac. It's isn't my first time that I installed it on a pc, but this time I really don't know how to install it. First thing what I did was to download the JDK 8 file to my Mac and installed it (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html), after that I dowloaded Netbeans 8.2 (version "All", https://netbeans.org/downloads/old/8.2/) and installed it. But now comes my problem, when begin installing it, a pop-up pops up (No Java found, NetBeans IDE cannot be installed. This software can be installed with Java 8 or newer. Please download and install the latest update of Java 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and restart NetBeans installation.) So now I am stuck. I have looked everywhere on the internet to find the problem solve it but found nothing. I would love to get some help with my problem. Thank you./(PS. I am new in the world of Mac-os. I have tried some advise's from stack overflow to get working with the terminal, but no success.)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it! I first needed to download "Homebrew" on my Mac and after that I downloaded Netbeans 8.2 in the terminal with this "brew install --cask netbeans-java-se" after that I needed to edit the my path and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

go to terminal then paste this command. 'brew install --cask netbeans'

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have solved my problem :). But it think that your comment will help other users :)

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since this question was originally asked.

#### I still prefer Homebrew, using the following steps:

1. Install Java:

```
brew install java
```

2. Symlink newly installed Homebrew Java to standard macOS Java VM location:

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

3. Add these lines near *top* of `.zshrc` or similar (but after Homebrew itself is exported):

```
# Java (at front of path)
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include
```

4. Install Netbeans

```
brew install netbeans
```

5. Done!